# Having trouble in initializing Matlab MCR when using a DLL, generated by matlab, in Unity3D

Tags: c#, matlab, unity-game-engine, dll

I am developing a Kinect based gesture recognizing application on Unity3D. I have to utilize an algorithm that has been written in Matlab. Thus I decided to generate a .Net DLL with Matlab deploytool and I successfully did so. Then I tested the DLL in a standalone .Net application project(in Visual Studio 2017) where it worked perfectly. BUT, when I turned to Unity3D, that DLL never worked...... What I got is shown as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkEmR.png)

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Untitled1.ADD ---> System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
  at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent (Boolean ifImpersonating) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Principal/WindowsIdentity.cs:166 
  at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.EvaluateFunction (System.String functionName, Int32 numArgsOut, Int32 numArgsIn, MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray[] argsIn) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.EvaluateFunction (Int32 numArgsOut, System.String functionName, MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray[] argsIn) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.setBuilderUserData () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR..ctor (System.String componentId, System.String componentPath, System.IO.Stream embeddedCtfStream, Boolean isLibrary) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Untitled1.ADD..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at dlltest.Start () [0x00000] in E:\Unity\mPrj\Assets\dlltest.cs:40 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
dlltest:Start() (at Assets/dlltest.cs:46)
```

From the Log, it seemed that the initializing of MCR was failed, but I just can not find why after viewing the C# source code generated by Matlab(who ever has done this job before must know what I am talking about). 
***Is there someone who is experienced in this kind of work and can explain to me this happened and how to solve? Thank you so much!***

The namespace of the DLL is *Untitled1*(got no time to give it a name...) and the name of the class in the DLL is *ADD*.
Followings are the related code in this process(test samples):

Matlab source code add.m:

```
   function y = add(n,m)

   y = n+m;
```

The C# Code, which is generated by Matlab during building the M file into DLL, is too long to paste here, so I just show the code that defines the constructor, at which the error in Unity3D happen according to the Log:

```
static ADD()
{
  if (MWMCR.MCRAppInitialized)
  {
    Assembly assembly= Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    string ctfFilePath= assembly.Location;

    int lastDelimiter= ctfFilePath.LastIndexOf(@"\");

    ctfFilePath= ctfFilePath.Remove(lastDelimiter, (ctfFilePath.Length - lastDelimiter));

    string ctfFileName = "Untitled1.ctf";

    Stream embeddedCtfStream = null;

    String[] resourceStrings = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

    foreach (String name in resourceStrings)
    {
      if (name.Contains(ctfFileName))
      {
        embeddedCtfStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name);
        break;
      }
    }
    mcr= new MWMCR("",
                   ctfFilePath, embeddedCtfStream, true);
  }
  else
  {
    throw new ApplicationException("MWArray assembly could not be initialized");
  }
}
```

The code that successfully used the DLL in a standalone .Net Application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using Untitled1;

namespace AddDllTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ADD myAdd = new ADD();

            Console.WriteLine(myAdd.add((MWArray)1, (MWArray)1));

        }
    }
}
```

And the code, which is a Unity3D script, that failed to use the DLL in Unity3D(some comments have been deleted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using RootSystem = System;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using Untitled1;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;

public class dlltest : MonoBehaviour {

    MWArray test1 = 1;
    MWArray ref0 = 2;
    MWArray result;
    ADD myADD;

    //Use this for initializations
    void Start () {

        try
        {
            myADD = new ADD();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("EXCEPTION");

            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        result = myADD.add(test1,ref0);
        Debug.Log(result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the static ctor of *MWMCR* class is calling into an unsupported method in Mono classlib:

(https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/uniy-trunk/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Principal/WindowsIdentity.cs#L166)

The reason your test worked as a standalone .Net is that you probably is running it on CLR.

When you try to run your Unity project it uses Mono (in most cases) and then you get this error.

It should work if you build your Unity project as a "Windows Store App" (because in this case your "game" will run using CLR)